# How to uninstall everything from $GOPATH/bin?

Tags: go

The `go clean -i` command that is ran inside some project deletes an executable file of that particular project that was previously installed by `go install` command. How to delete **everything** installed by the `go install` commands that were ran from several **different** projects? Is there some single `go` command that can do that?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `rm -rf "$GOPATH/bin"`?

Comment: It's not consistent with `go clean -modcache` that knows to delete all downloaded modules in the neighbor `$GOPATH/pkg` directory. It's not consistent with the `go` command set in general. If something was installed by `go` it should be able to be removed by `go`.

Comment: "If something was installed by go it should be able to be removed by go." Why? Any technical reason beyond "I want". The module cache is complicated and it's a cache maintained and owned by the go tool. GOPATH/bin is neither.

Comment: @RostislavKrasny "should" is your opinion. It does not. Installing a binary places *a single file*. There is no reason for any special tooling to delete a single file.

Comment: @Volker The reason is similar to use package manager even in source based Linux distros and not `make install`. There is a `go` command that install executable, a `go` command that removes an executable of the current project but no `go` command to manage all executables in the `$GOPATH/bin`. This is wrong.

Comment: @Adrian You're wrong. There is already a tooling to delete a single file - `go clean -i`.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Delete the binary like any other file.

---

The "install" term means place (something) in a new position ready for use.
Therefore, Go builds a single-file binary and places it in another directory (`$GOPATH/bin`). It is useful when you add the Go binary directory into the environment variable to call the program.

There's no auxiliary flag such as `go clean -bincache` to remove all binaries installed by Go 1.16.4.

However, at the current version of GoLang (1.16.4), the right way to remove (or "uninstall" as you said) any installed binary is solely to delete it, like any other file despite you feel it sounds awkward.